# Removing theme from one slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I remove the theme for just one slide in microsoft powerpoint? Assume I have applied a theme which has picture. Now I want to remove that for just one slide because the contents have overlap with pictures and it is not looking good.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which version of Powerpoint you are using. This solution works for Powerpoint 2007 and upwards, you can give it a try too.

Step 1: Select the slide for which you want to change the theme

Step 2: Go to the Design Tab / Section and locate the theme that you want to apply, but don't apply it yet

Step 3: Right click on the theme and select 'Apply to Selected Slides'

This will change the theme for that single or multiple slides for which you wish to change the theme..

Comment: This works, but not if you want to apply a theme from a file (i.e., "Browse for themes"). If you want to do that, you cannot right click on the theme.